# Sum variables by unique variable names, for different metrics - requires finding unique names before/after a prefix in variable name

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, summary

Is there is a way to sum variables (e.g. sales and units) for all unique variable names (brands like coke and pepsi) within a dataframe.
To help, here is some example data.

```
set.seed(123)
period <- seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), as.Date('2021/01/07'), by="day")
Coke_Regular_Units <- sample(1000:2000, 7, replace = TRUE)
Coke_Diet_Units <- sample(1000:2000, 7, replace = TRUE)
Coke_Regular_Sales <- sample(500:1000,7, replace = TRUE)
Coke_Diet_Sales <- sample(500:1000, 7, replace = TRUE)
Pepsi_Regular_Units  <- sample(1000:2000, 7, replace = TRUE)
Pepsi_Diet_Units  <- sample(1000:2000, 7, replace = TRUE)
Pepsi_Regular_Sales <- sample(500:1000, 7, replace = TRUE)
Pepsi_Diet_Sales <- sample(500:1000, 7, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(Coke_Regular_Units, Coke_Diet_Units, Coke_Regular_Sales, Coke_Diet_Sales, 
                 Pepsi_Regular_Units, Pepsi_Diet_Units, Pepsi_Regular_Sales, Pepsi_Diet_Sales)

> head(df)
      period Coke_Regular_Units Coke_Diet_Units Coke_Regular_Sales Coke_Diet_Sales Pepsi_Regular_Units
1 2021-01-01               1414            1117                589             847                1425
2 2021-01-02               1462            1298                590             636                1648
3 2021-01-03               1178            1228                755             976                1765
4 2021-01-04               1525            1243                696             854                1210
5 2021-01-05               1194            1013                998             827                1931
6 2021-01-06               1937            1373                590             525                1589
  Pepsi_Diet_Units Pepsi_Regular_Sales Pepsi_Diet_Sales
1             1554                 608              943
2             1870                 762              808
3             1372                 892              634
4             1843                 924              808
5             1142                 829              910
6             1543                 522              723
```

I like a code to automatically calculate Coke_Sales, Coke_Units, Pepsi_Sales, Pepsi_Units,  Regular_Sales and Diet_Units.

I am currently doing it like this for each variable

```
library(dplyr) 
df$Coke_Sales <- rowSums(Filter(is.numeric, select(df, (matches("Coke") & matches("Sales")))))
df$Coke_Units <- rowSums(Filter(is.numeric, select(df, (matches("Coke") & matches("Units")))))
```

This is ok for a small number of variables, but I need to do this for 100s of variables. Is there any function that enables this? It would need to automatically find the unique variable names like Coke, Pepsi, Diet and Regular. The metric is the last part of the variable name, so doesn't necessarily need to auto-find this but would be great. If it makes it any easier, it would be ok to specify the metrics as  there are only 3 metrics at most, but there are hundreds of brands.

If it cant be automated, is there a way it can be simplified, where I specify the variables required. Not perfect but still an improvement. For example including these lines of code to specify variables to sum and metrics required.

```
VarsToSum <- c("Coke", "Pepsi", "Diet", "Regular")
Metrics <- c("Sales", "Units")
```

If it can't be accomplished that way either, maybe I need to break into smaller steps, any tips would be great. Trying to think how to do it, should I try to find unique name before a prefix "_", then calculate "Sales" and "Units" for those unique names.  Would this be the best way to do it? Or should I reshape the data? Are there any other routes to get there?

Any help, or directions how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table`approach...

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df) #make it a data.table
#melt to long
ans <- melt( df, id.vars = "period", variable.factor = FALSE )
#split variable to 3 new columns
ans[, c("brand", "type", "what") := tstrsplit( variable, "_" ) ]
# > head(ans)
#        period           variable value brand    type  what
# 1: 2021-01-01 Coke_Regular_Units  1414  Coke Regular Units
# 2: 2021-01-02 Coke_Regular_Units  1462  Coke Regular Units
# 3: 2021-01-03 Coke_Regular_Units  1178  Coke Regular Units
# 4: 2021-01-04 Coke_Regular_Units  1525  Coke Regular Units
# 5: 2021-01-05 Coke_Regular_Units  1194  Coke Regular Units
# 6: 2021-01-06 Coke_Regular_Units  1937  Coke Regular Units

#summarise however you like
ans[, .(total = sum(value) ), by = .(brand, type, what)]
#    brand    type  what total
# 1:  Coke Regular Units 10527
# 2:  Coke    Diet Units  8936
# 3:  Coke Regular Sales  5158
# 4:  Coke    Diet Sales  5171
# 5: Pepsi Regular Units 11160
# 6: Pepsi    Diet Units 10813
# 7: Pepsi Regular Sales  5447
# 8: Pepsi    Diet Sales  5491
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `outer` for `paste`ing the syllables and `grep`.

```
sapply(outer(c("Coke", "Pepsi"), c("Sales", "Units"), paste, sep=".*"), function(x)
  rowSums(df[grep(x, names(df))]))
#      Coke.*Sales Pepsi.*Sales Coke.*Units Pepsi.*Units
# [1,]        1436         1551        2531         2979
# [2,]        1226         1570        2760         3518
# [3,]        1731         1526        2406         3137
# [4,]        1550         1732        2768         3053
# [5,]        1825         1739        2207         3073
# [6,]        1115         1245        3310         3132
# [7,]        1446         1575        3481         3081
```

Comment: This could be problematic if the brand name is contained within another brand name, Maybe unusual but more likely if a subsidiary it were Apple and Apple Corp. But very useful if the brands are known and distinct. Many thanks a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution similar in spirit to that of @Wimpel, but with the `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)

summary_df  <-
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("Sales") | ends_with("Units"),
              names_to = c("brand", "type", ".value"),
              names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)_(.*)") %>%
  group_by(brand) %>%
  summarize(Sales = sum(Sales),
            Units = sum(Units)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "brand",
              values_from = c("Sales", "Units"),
              names_glue = "{brand}_{.value}")

  summary_df
  # # A tibble: 1 x 4
  #   Coke_Sales Pepsi_Sales Coke_Units Pepsi_Units
  #       <int>       <int>      <int>       <int>
  # 1      10329       10938      19463       21973
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this. This is an overall sum for the variable. Is there an adjustment I can make to the code to make a new variable in dataframe (whereby it's sum for each row)?

Comment: solved it, I need to adjust the above with part with  **group_by(period, brand) %>%** thanks